# What should I do if I should delete registered user from my db but it has a lot of connections that I don`t want to remove (in my project)?

Tags: sql, database-administration

I try to understand what I should do when the user will ask to delete his account from the app, but it has a lot of info connected to this user and I should leave it. Is it okay if I just make couple of columns null?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have a `Status` column in your `user` table and you can make the Status `Active` or `Inactive`. You can use `Inactive` to represent a "deleted" user. This way, any data the user created can remain intact, along with all referential integrity relationships.